# How to tell package manager that dependencies are already installed?

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, dependencies, pacman

I'm running Arch Linux, and I have texlive 2013 installed from CTAN, not from repositories. Now when I try to install lilypond via pacman, it wants texlive-bin-2013.30973-7 and texlive-core-2013.31589-1 as dependencies.

I guess there must be a way to point to my existing texlive, but what is it exactly?

These threads ("[Installing from source. How to resolve dependencies without destroying the package manager.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43952/installing-from-source-how-to-resolve-dependencies-without-destroying-the-packa)", "[Package installation and dependancies - how to prevent installation of existing libraries?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47869/package-installation-and-dependancies-how-to-prevent-installation-of-existing)") don't seem to answer my question. Do I need to involve into something like "[Link a dependency in Synaptic to the one already installed from source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13436/link-a-dependency-in-synaptic-to-the-one-already-installed-from-source)"?

Comment: The simplest, sanest approach would be just to use pacman to manage your packages.

Comment: Do you mean, (re)install texlive with pacman, not from ctan?

Comment: Yes. Remove the untracked packages, install texlive with pacman and then you won't have to worry about it all going pear shaped down the track (which it *will* with your current approach).

Comment: My approach actually stemmed from the belief (please correct me if I'm wrong) that the ctan installation provides a fuller and more up-to-date version of texlive than the distro-specific installations do. Maybe it's the case with Ubuntu but not Arch?

Comment: That's probably true for Ubuntu. Arch uses vanilla packages and pushes them to the repos as they are released upstream. You can install all of the tex-* packages you require using pacman (or makepkg if they are in the AUR) and be up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you (and everybody else)! Should I make that an answer or just leave it as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @jasonwryan for advice, I did the following:

First, I removed my old installation:

```
# rm -rf /usr/local/texlive
$ rm -rf ~/.texlive2013
```

Then I just installed lilypond with pacman, which pulled texlive-core and texlive-bin as dependencies:

```
# pacman -S lilypond
```

Then I installed some optional dependencies (psutils and t1utils), followed by texlive-lang and texlive-most:

```
# pacman -S psutils t1utils
# pacman -S texlive-lang texlive-most
```

Both tex and lilypond work, yay for Arch and pacman.

Answer (score 3):

Option would be to create "virtual" (read empty) package for it. With Arch creating your own packages is very easy. Just take inspiration from existing PKGBUILDs and adjust "Provides" accordingly.

Comment: There is an AUR-package: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/texlive-dummy/

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestion. Even though I opted for a different move, that still seems like a possible solution to other problems.